# Tensorflow synchronous gradient GD getting hung after one epoch on master

Tags: synchronization, tensorflow, synchronized, gradient-descent

I have the following code (below) to perform tensorflow synchronous gradient descent based on their example here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/inception_distributed_train.py

## Run With

The command I'm using for running this session on a cluster i have access to is:

`(python2 SyncSGD.py --job_name='ps' --task_index=0 &) && (python2 SyncSGD.py --job_name='worker' --task_index=0 &) && (python2 SyncSGD.py --job_name='worker' --task_index=1 &) && (python2 SyncSGD.py --job_name='worker' --task_index==2 &)`

## The Problem

For some reason the additional worker threads never really advance past the `sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session` call. The master thread (`FLAGS.task_index==0`) runs one full epoch of operations and then just hangs or times out. After killing all the threads or waiting for timeout the the other worker threads advance past the call to `sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session`; however, they print indication that they've made it to the first epoch and hang.

#### Non reproducible

This also doesn't happen all the time. Sometimes the master never gets past the first epoch's run opteration, and the other two end up eventually catching up after about 30 sec and then also get hung at the run-op. Other times some threads will make it through some random number of epochs of training (one thread will make 2 epochs, the other two only 1). Sometimes, it even finishes. I have no idea what causes this; however, it seems like there's huge synchronization problems with the Supervisor(coordinator wrapper) and SyncReplicasOptimizer. I have searched profusely and still have no idea what to actually search to fix this and it's really my last resort.

## The Code

```
from __future__ import print_function

import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.platform import app
import sys
import time

# input flags
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("job_name", "", "Either 'ps' or 'worker'")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("task_index", 0, "Index of task within the job")
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS



class SynchSGD:

  def __init__(self,parameter_servers,workers ):
    self.parameter_servers=parameter_servers
    self.workers=workers
    self.cluster = tf.train.ClusterSpec({"ps":parameter_servers, "worker":workers})
    # start a server for a specific task
    self.server = tf.train.Server(self.cluster,
                          job_name=FLAGS.job_name,
                          task_index=FLAGS.task_index)



  def run(self,fetches,fetches_format,dataset,batch_size=1,test_dataset=None,learning_rate=0.001,test_fetches_format=None,training_epochs=20, logs_path='/tmp/mnist/1'):

    if FLAGS.job_name == "ps":
      self.server.join()
    elif FLAGS.job_name == "worker":

      # Between-graph replication
      with tf.device(tf.train.replica_device_setter(
        worker_device="/job:worker/task:%d/cpu:0" % (FLAGS.task_index),#FLAGS.task_index),
        cluster=self.cluster)):

        print(str(FLAGS.task_index),"b4 gloabl step")
        # count the number of updates
        global_step = tf.get_variable('global_step', [],
                                    initializer = tf.constant_initializer(0),
                                    trainable = False)
        print(str(FLAGS.task_index),"b4 fetches")
        inputs,fetches=fetches(learning_rate,global_step)
        if FLAGS.task_index == 0:
            chief_queue_runner = fetches[-1]
            init_token_op = fetches[-2]
        init_op = tf.initialize_all_variables()

      print(str(FLAGS.task_index),"b4 sv")
      sv = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(FLAGS.task_index == 0),
                                global_step=global_step,
                                init_op=init_op,
                                logdir=logs_path)

      begin_time = time.time()
      frequency = 100
      print(str(FLAGS.task_index),"b4 sesh")
      with sv.prepare_or_wait_for_session(self.server.target) as sess:
             # is chief
        print(str(FLAGS.task_index),"b4 qr")
        queue_runners = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.QUEUE_RUNNERS)
        sv.start_queue_runners(sess, queue_runners)
        print(str(FLAGS.task_index)," after qr")
        if FLAGS.task_index == 0:
          sv.start_queue_runners(sess, [chief_queue_runner])
          sess.run(init_token_op)
        print(str(FLAGS.task_index)," after cqr")


        if 'summary' in fetches_format:
          # create log writer object (this will log on every machine)
          writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(logs_path, graph=tf.get_default_graph())

        # perform training cycles
        start_time = time.time()
        for epoch in range(training_epochs):

          # number of batches in one epoch
          batch_count = int(dataset.num_examples/batch_size)

          count = 0
          print(str(FLAGS.task_index),str(epoch))
          for i in range(batch_count):
            batch_x, batch_y = dataset.next_batch(batch_size)
            # perform the operations we defined earlier on batch
            result = sess.run(
                            fetches[:-2],
                            feed_dict={inputs[0]: batch_x, inputs[1]: batch_y})
            print(str(FLAGS.task_index),str(i))
            if 'summary' in fetches_format:
              writer.add_summary(result[fetches_format['summary']], result[fetches_format['step']])

            count += 1
            if count % frequency == 0 or i+1 == batch_count:
              elapsed_time = time.time() - start_time
              start_time = time.time()
              std_out=''
              count = 0

      #sv.stop()

def main(argv=None):
  # cluster specification
  parameter_servers = ["localhost:2222"]
  workers = [ "localhost:2223",
        "localhost:2224",
        "localhost:2225"]

  # config
  batch_size = 100
  learning_rate = 0.001
  training_epochs = 3
  logs_path = "/rscratch/cs194/psharing-neural-nets/sync-logging"

  #create variables for model
  def fetches(learning_rate, global_step):
    # input images
    with tf.name_scope('input'):
      # None -> batch size can be any size, 784 -> flattened mnist image
      x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 784], name="x-input")
      # target 10 output classes
      y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, 10], name="y-input")

    # model parameters will change during training so we use tf.Variable
    tf.set_random_seed(1)
    with tf.name_scope("weights"):
      W1 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, 100]))
      W2 = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([100, 10]))

    # bias
    with tf.name_scope("biases"):
      b1 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([100]))
      b2 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([10]))

    # implement model
    with tf.name_scope("softmax"):
      # y is our prediction
      z2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(x,W1),b1)
      a2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(z2)
      z3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(a2,W2),b2)
      y  = tf.nn.softmax(z3)

    # specify cost function
    with tf.name_scope('cross_entropy'):
      # this is our cost
      cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

    # specify optimizer
    with tf.name_scope('train'):
      # optimizer is an "operation" which we can execute in a session
      grad_op = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate)
      print('len workers %d: '%FLAGS.task_index,str(len(workers)))
      rep_op = tf.train.SyncReplicasOptimizer(grad_op,
                                          replicas_to_aggregate=len(workers),
                                          replica_id=FLAGS.task_index,
                                          total_num_replicas=len(workers),
                                          use_locking=True
                                          )
      grads = rep_op.compute_gradients(cross_entropy)
      apply_gradients_op = rep_op.apply_gradients(grads,global_step=global_step)
      with tf.control_dependencies([apply_gradients_op]):
        train_op=tf.identity(cross_entropy,name='train_op')
      #train_op = rep_op.minimize(cross_entropy, global_step=global_step)
      #train_op = grad_op.minimize(cross_entropy, global_step=global_step)

    init_token_op = rep_op.get_init_tokens_op()
    chief_queue_runner = rep_op.get_chief_queue_runner()

    with tf.name_scope('Accuracy'):
      # accuracy
      correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))
      accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

    # create a summary for our cost and accuracy
    tf.scalar_summary("cost", cross_entropy)
    tf.scalar_summary("accuracy", accuracy)
    # merge all summaries into a single "operation" which we can execute in a session
    summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    return [x,y_],[train_op, cross_entropy, summary_op, global_step, accuracy, init_token_op, chief_queue_runner]

  # load mnist data set
  from tensorflow.examples.tutorials.mnist import input_data
  dataset = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True).train
  test_dataset = input_data.read_data_sets('MNIST_data', one_hot=True).test

  fetches_format = {'train':0,'cost':1,'summary':2,'step':3}
  test_fetches_format = {'accuracy':0}

  sgd=SynchSGD(parameter_servers,workers)
  sgd.run(fetches,fetches_format,dataset,batch_size=batch_size,learning_rate=learning_rate,test_dataset=test_dataset,training_epochs=training_epochs, logs_path=logs_path)

if __name__=="__main__":
  app.run()
```

## Other Bugs

For some reason it seems to be creating a bunch of other jobs (looks like a job for communication with the other jobs maybe)
producing the following mem allocations on 8 K40s (the python2 jobs)

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory | 
|  GPU       PID  Type  Process name                               Usage      |                                                                                                                                                             
|=============================================================================|                                                                                                                                                             
|    0     26489    C   ./train-imagenet-sgd                          8598MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    0     28733    C   python2                                        389MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    0     28735    C   python2                                        123MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    0     28737    C   python2                                        106MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    0     28739    C   python2                                       2976MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    1     26489    C   ./train-imagenet-sgd                          8598MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    1     28733    C   python2                                        206MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    1     28735    C   python2                                        306MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    1     28737    C   python2                                        106MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    1     28739    C   python2                                       2976MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    2     26489    C   ./train-imagenet-sgd                          8598MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    2     28733    C   python2                                        206MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    2     28735    C   python2                                        306MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    2     28737    C   python2                                        106MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    2     28739    C   python2                                       2974MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    3     26489    C   ./train-imagenet-sgd                          8598MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    3     28733    C   python2                                        206MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    3     28735    C   python2                                        306MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    3     28737    C   python2                                        106MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    3     28739    C   python2                                       2974MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    4     26489    C   ./train-imagenet-sgd                          8598MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    4     28733    C   python2                                        206MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    4     28735    C   python2                                        286MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    4     28737    C   python2                                        106MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    4     28739    C   python2                                       2976MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    5     26489    C   ./train-imagenet-sgd                          8598MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    5     28733    C   python2                                       2976MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    5     28735    C   python2                                        306MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    5     28737    C   python2                                        106MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    5     28739    C   python2                                        206MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    6     26489    C   ./train-imagenet-sgd                          8704MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    6     28733    C   python2                                        206MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    6     28735    C   python2                                        106MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    6     28737    C   python2                                        106MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    6     28739    C   python2                                        106MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    7     26489    C   ./train-imagenet-sgd                          8598MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    7     28733    C   python2                                        107MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    7     28735    C   python2                                        106MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    7     28737    C   python2                                        106MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
|    7     28739    C   python2                                        106MiB |                                                                                                                                                             
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

If the other jobs weren't there it would've allocated way more jobs (and still erred). Producing this giant stream of failed mem allocations:

```
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 2.80G (3009019904 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 2.80G (3009019904 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 2.80G (3009019904 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 2.52G (2708117760 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 2.52G (2708117760 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 2.52G (2708117760 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 2.27G (2437305856 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 2.27G (2437305856 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 2.27G (2437305856 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 2.04G (2193575168 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 2.04G (2193575168 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 2.04G (2193575168 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.84G (1974217728 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.84G (1974217728 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.84G (1974217728 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.65G (1776795904 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.65G (1776795904 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.65G (1776795904 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.49G (1599116288 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.49G (1599116288 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.49G (1599116288 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.34G (1439204608 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.34G (1439204608 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.34G (1439204608 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.21G (1295284224 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.21G (1295284224 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.21G (1295284224 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.08G (1165755904 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.08G (1165755904 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1.08G (1165755904 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1000.58M (1049180416 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1000.58M (1049180416 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 1000.58M (1049180416 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 900.52M (944262400 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 900.52M (944262400 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 900.52M (944262400 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 810.47M (849836288 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 810.47M (849836288 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 810.47M (849836288 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 729.42M (764852736 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 729.42M (764852736 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 729.42M (764852736 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 656.48M (688367616 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 656.48M (688367616 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 656.48M (688367616 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 590.83M (619531008 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 590.83M (619531008 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 590.83M (619531008 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 531.75M (557577984 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 531.75M (557577984 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 531.75M (557577984 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 478.57M (501820160 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 478.57M (501820160 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 478.57M (501820160 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 430.72M (451638272 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 430.72M (451638272 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:965] failed to allocate 430.72M (451638272 bytes) from device: CUDA_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY
```

I've tried for 4 days to get this to work and it's due tmrw so any help is appreciated

Comment: Debugging distributed race conditions is really hard. Have you tried using the sync replicas optimizer in tensorflow proper? https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/training/sync_replicas_optimizer.py

Comment: Hi Thanks @AlexandrePassos. Yes I've used the sync replicas optimizer to make the rep_op in the fetches() function defined in main